# How to create the REST API for this curl operation in PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

I want executed this simple curl operation through php how can i execute this in simple php not any framework , can i do it in simple php or do i need the framework?

```
curl -XPOST localhost:12060/repository/schema/fieldType -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
{
  action: "create",
  fieldType: {
    name: "n$name",
    valueType: { primitive: "STRING" },
    scope: "versioned",
    namespaces: { "my.demo": "n" }
  }
}' -D -
```

what i tried is :

```
<?php
$url="localhost:12060/repository/schema/fieldType";     
//open connection
$options = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, // return web page
CURLOPT_HEADER => false, // don't return headers
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true, // follow redirects
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", // handle all encodings
CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "spider", // who am i
CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true, // set referer on redirect
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120, // timeout on connect
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120, // timeout on response
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, // stop after 10 redirects
);
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$fieldString=array(
    "action"=> "create",
    "fieldType"=>array(
        "name"=> "n$name",
        "valueType"=> array( "primitive"=> "STRING" ),
        "scope"=> "versioned",
        "namespaces"=> array( "my.demo"=> "n" )
    )
);
//for some diff
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADERS, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode("{json: $fieldString}"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$header = curl_getinfo( $ch );
echo $result;
//close connection
curl_close($ch);




?>
```

But it is giving me this

```
The given resource variant is not supported.Please use one of the following: * Variant[mediaType=application/json, language=null, encoding=null]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode("{json: $fieldString}"));
```

The `$fieldString` is not actually an string as its name implies. It was an array at this point still. And you are trying to reencode an mangled faux json string, with just `Array` as data. Won't work.

Instead use this to get the desired(?) effect:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fieldString));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357900/content-type-not-changing-with-curlopt-httpheaders

Comment: changed headers to header but now i am getting an error in JSON error bad Request 400 no. error, this is the part of JSON{"message":"Invalid qualified name, does not contain a $: n",} , but when i run through CURL it gives me 409 error about that entry already exist.

Comment: Please read and understand the error message. -- Use single quotes for the `$fieldString` data array. (Either all of it, or just the one entry that uses string interpolation otherwise.)

Comment: okay got it problem was with the n$name added this in single quotes